# mongodb c++ QString to kvp() value

Tags: qt, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I'm struggling to get a valid conversion of my qstring to whatever kvp needs inside mongo...

I tried

```
std::string_view k(documentKey.toStdString().c_str());//, documentKey.size()); // tried adding size as wll
std::string_view v(documentId.toStdString().c_str());//, documentId.size());
```

and then:

```
auto doc = mCollection.find(make_document(kvp(k, v)));
```

But I keep on getting empty results. If I type directly k/v as "someKey", "someValue" it works just fine. But I can't figure out how to convert it from one to another... any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

kvp can be built with two strings, so if `.toStdString()` returns a valid string this should work for you:

```
std::string docKey = documentKey.toStdString();
std::string docId = documentId.toStdString();
auto doc = mCollection.find(make_document(kvp(docKey, docId)));
```

Please keep in mind that if the `_id` is automatically generated by mongo you'll need to use an [ObjectId](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/e51c515ace89bab528942fdfae0f6d31d9150a66/src/bsoncxx/oid.hpp#L29) type instead.

Comment: Hey I managed to get it to work. Ended up being a quite interesting issue as I could not use toStdString() due to the way mongo was taking the arg. I had to pre-declare it above. I'll post an answer with how I solved it.